# Swift: Modeling a variable with multiple types

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, variables, modeling

I'm building an alarm app where each alarm has a sound associated with it.

The sound can either be a song, artist([song]), or playlist([song]); all of which have a title and other specific properties.

I'd like to be able to do things like alarm.sound.title and have the title return regardless of if it's a song, artist, or playlist. I also need to implement logic where the app behaves differently depending on whether it's a song, artist, or playlist.

I'm not sure if I should be creating a sound class with a type property and subclasses song, artist, playlist or if there is a better way to structure the data. I read about typecasting but I'm not sure if that's the right direction.

Any advice on how to model this would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You're describing the classic (pun almost intended) case of interface polymorphism in the land of classic OOP, where you'd define an abstract base class (or interface) called Song, and concrete subclasses. You can do the subclass thing in Swift, or you could make Song a protocol. No need to typecast.

Comment: Depending on what properties you need exactly, you might also be able to use an enum with associated values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want to use Swift I'd suggest using protocols. That would give what you need. Simple example:

```
protocol Sound {
    let title: String { get }
    let length: TimeInterval { get }
}
```

The protocol would define the interface. Then you can just create various classes which would conform to the protocol - the underlaying implementation can be completely different:

```
class Song: Sound {
    var title: String
    var length: TimeInterval

    init(title: String, length: TimeInterval) {
        self.title = title
        self.length = length
    }
}

class Artist: Sound {
    var title: String {
        return "Artist"
    }
    var length: TimeInterval {
        return 11.1
    }
}
```

Then you can simply access `title` on any object conforming to the `Sound` protocol:

```
let sound1: Sound = Song(title: "Song", length: 1)
let sound2: Sound = Artist()

print("\(sound1.title)")  // prints: Song
print("\(sound2.title)")  // prints: Artist
```

Comment: Thanks Tom, in this example how would I model the alarm?

Comment: The `sound` is a property of `Alarm`, correct? So you could add `let sound: Sound` to your `Alarm` class. I'd probably use Factory pattern to create the `Alarm` with appropriate sound.

Comment: Seems like I have a bit more learning to do but thanks for sending me in the right direction.

Comment: I got everything implemented the way you suggested. The only problem I ran into is now Alarm doesn't conform to Codeable. I read that you can't conform protocols to themselves so how would I go about doing that?

Comment: Classes/structs can conform to multiple protocols. `class Alarm: Sound, Codeable { ... }` does not work?

Comment: I added let sound: Sound to the Alarm class but Sound does not conform to codable. Why would I conform Alarm to the Sound protocol?

Comment: Ah sorry, the `Sound` is inside the `Alarm`, you are correct. The reason why the `Alarm` does not conform to `Codable` is likely because you custom `Sound` class - it doesn't know how to code that. Try to add `Codable` to your `Sound` class (and other custom classes/structs used inside `Alarm`).